# ¿Como puedo obtener los productos que sufrieron aumentos entre 2 fechas diferentes?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Quiero obtener los productos que aumentaron entre dos fechas...

Tengo las siguientes tablas:

producto <pid PK, descripcion, tipo, contenido>

tipo <tipo PK, descripcion>

comercio <comercio PK, nombre, direccion, barrio, zona>

precio <pid PK FK, comercio PK FK, fecha_registro PK, precio>

Por Ejemplo: Yo se que el producto 130 vario su precio entre 2012 y 2015, ¿Como puedo agregarlo a mi consulta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas agrupar los precios por `pid` filtrando por la fecha deseada, se cuenta la cantidad de filas de cada grupo y filtramos mediante el `HAVING` aquellos productos que tuvieran más de un precio en el período

```
SELECT pid,
       COUNT(precio)
       FROM precio
       WHERE fecha_registro BETWEEN '20120101' AND '20151231'
       GROUP BY pid
       HAVING COUNT(precio) > 1
```

Lo anterior lo puedes usar como subconsulta para finalmente obtener los productos:

```
SELECT *
       FROM producto
       WHERE pid IN (SELECT pid,
                            COUNT(precio)
                            FROM precio
                            WHERE fecha_registro BETWEEN '20120101' AND '20151231'
                            GROUP BY pid
                            HAVING COUNT(precio) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza el operador between. Si precisas de pasar las fechas al SQL como literales, utiliza el formato YYYYMMDD que, en mi experiencia, funciona siempre, independientemente del idioma/cultura en que esté configurado el servidor y el cliente del SQL Server, en resumen, para ver los datos del primer semestre del 2016, la consulta sería algo similar a:

```
select *
  from miTabla
 where Fecha between '20160101' and '20160630';
```

Si los campos son tipo DateTime, podrías querer incluir información de la hora, para ese caso, siguiendo con el ejemplo de uso de literales, puedes valerte del formato YYYYMMDD HH24:MM:SS, por ejemplo:

```
select *
  from miTabla
 where Fecha between '20160101 00:00:00' and '20160630 23:59:59';
```

La recomendación es, siempre que sea posible, pasar los valores de fechas como parámetros, pero la sintaxis final dependerá de las capacidades de la capa de conexión a datos de tu lenguaje de programación.

Comment: ¿Y como se que productos variaron su precio? Porque con la fecha sola no me sirve...

Comment: Fecha es solo un campo, puedes cambiarlo por el campo que necesites

Comment: 1) obtienes los productos modificados en tal fecha

Comment: 2) filtras entre esos productos los que sus precios variaron